# update a column based on another column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following records

```
column A   | Column B
19-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~~122
NULL       | SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~122
20-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~~128
NULL       | SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~128
```

I need to update `Column A` that has `NULL` with not NULL VALUE based on SQHDB012384_3 `(string before 1st '~')`  and 122 `(string after last '~')`

My output  after the update should be

```
column A   | Column B
19-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~~122
19-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~122
20-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~~128
20-OCT-16  | SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~128
```

Comment: Try `UPDATE "table" SET "Column A" = '19-OCT-16' WHERE "Column A" IS NULL AND "Column B" LIKE 'SQHDB012384_3~%~122'`...

Comment: Hi Usagi,I need to write a generic query as if there are multiple records.

Comment: Well in this case you have to specify concrete conditions, including: which value to use if there are more than one rows to copy from...

Comment: Hi Usagi - There will be always one row to copy from.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET Column A = 
(case 
WHEN column B LIKE 'SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~122' then'19-OCT-16'
WHEN column B LIKE 'SQHDB012384_3~SOHDB006408~128' then '20-OCT-16'
ELSE column A
end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MERGE INTO`  with a simple `REGEXP_LIKE` and `JOIN`.

```
MERGE INTO mytable r
USING (SELECT b.columnb,
              a.columna new_val
       FROM   mytable a
              inner join mytable b
                      ON Regexp_like (b.columnb,
                         Replace(a.columnb, '~~', '~.+~'))
       WHERE  b.columnb != a.columnb
              AND b.columna IS NULL) m
ON ( m.columnb = r.columnb )
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET r.columna = m.new_val;
```

Comment: Let me no why the question has been downvoted ?  It's a tested code.

Answer (score -1):

My version with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
UPDATE tableA A
SET ColumnA = ( SELECT ColumnA FROM tableA B
                WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.columnB, '^[^~]*~') ||
                      REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.columnB, '~[^~]*$') =
                      REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.columnB, '^[^~]*~') ||
                      REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.columnB, '~[^~]*$') 
WHERE ColumnA IS NULL
```